# Strange things happening when I enter my password on the lockscreen at Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I am running Windows 8.1 Professional x64 NL.

I have the following issue(s) whenever I lock my screen (windows-key + L):
- the select display pops up when I enter my password which contains the 'P' key;
- the accessibility thing which increases text size pops up when I press the 'Enter' key.

This leads me to believe my keyboard is playing jokes on me, somehow causing the 'Windows' key to be pressed simultaneously when I press the 'P' key when I enter my password.

I do not have a clue why I get the text size increase thing when I press enter.

I have come up with the following possible causes:

1. My keyboard's drivers are maybe causing this (I've got a Razer BlackWidow Ultimate keyboard), though the drivers are up-to-date

For as far as I know I do not have any viruses and not any strange settings set, this problem occurred before I had Windows 8.1 (so it also happened when I had 8), I cannot remember when this started to appear but it has not bothered me that much up untill now.

Does anybody else have this same problem or seen it before? And, do you please know a solution (where I don't have to reinstall my system).

Comment: Can you confirm that you're not using any keyboard mapping? Also, is this a laptop or desktop? Does the same issue occur with another keyboard?

Comment: This is a desktop. I am using macros on my keyboard, but when entering my password or locking the computer, I do not use a macro to do this. I only use the macros while the computer is unlocked. I do not have another keyboard to test this I am afraid :(

Comment: Can you make sure the chipset driver is also update. Other than that, I can't help as I think you need to borrow a different keyboard as this will pin point where the issue is. (-1 wasn't me)

Comment: I just verified using the 'Intel® Driver Update Utility' that the chipset drivers are up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks for informing me you weren't the one giving a -1, I dno who did, though?

Comment: Anyhow, I've tried with another keyboard and it seems to work fine. So it must be driver related (or hardware, since my Razer keyboard has software in it), so it could be firmware related. Maybe it would be a good choice to open a ticket @Razer's!

Comment: To solve the issue, you need to do a firmware update of your keyboard (I'm a bit late with this info since I solved this a long time ago). But I thought I'd post it here so that this can be of use to anybody else having this issue :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in the comments of original post as a driver update

Comment: It is not a driver update, but a firmware update. As I stated before, driver updates did not solve the issue, but a firmware update did.

The question however is not "off-topic" as I am pretty sure a lot of users with Razer keyboards are experiencing this issue and will get here by googling their issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, you need to do a firmware update of your keyboard (I'm a bit late with this info since I solved this a long time ago). So not a driver update, but a firmware update of your keyboard.

Apparently my keyboard did not update the firmware automatically due to a bug which does not allow "firmware update acces" to the keyboard (bascially the Razer software tries to update your keyboard's firmware every now and then automatically, but does not succeed).

I had to start the update process manually (unplug keyboard, hold "fn-key" then plug back in while holding "fn-key" - visit the Razer site for the full manual on updating your keyboard's firmware).

But I thought I'd post it here so that this can be of use to anybody else having this issue :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue after updating to Win 8.1 on 2 different machines.  In order to fix I have to press the start button (on the keyboard) and P.

Very frustrating and I am surprised more people haven't had the same issue

Comment: I have found that pressing the 'Windows' key before entering anything solves the issue. However, you need to do this everytime you enter your password. I also updated to 8.1, just like you. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem. For me, the problem appeared after I updated to the latest version of Razer Synapse. I'm running Windows 8.1 with a Razer BlackWidow keyboard. As a workaround, I click the back button on the lock screen as if to choose a different user to login with. Then click my account again and entering the password seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your keyboard is having issues, probably. It sounds as though your computer thinks the Windows key is being pressed. I've seen this happen with cheaper keyboards with the CTRL key seeming to be pressed.

With your nicer keyboard, I'm not certain of the cause.

But Win+P is the projector/second screen shortcut, and Win+Enter is the Narrator shortcut.

When this happens to me (with the CTRL key), I just hit the CTRL key a few times and it fixes itself. You can try pressing the Win key a few times to see if the issues goes away.

Comment: Yes, like I said, pressing the 'Windows' key solves the issue, however, I need to do this everytime that I lock my computer. Seeing as there are so many people having this issue, maybe we should make a ticket @Razer's?